# Stuck with following question on primary decomposition theorem.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, primary-decomposition

Let $T$ an operator over a $\mathbb{F}$ vector space $\mathbb{V}$, with $\dim(\mathbb{V})<\infty$. Let $p=p_{1}^{r_{1}}\cdots p_{k}^{r_{k}}$ the minimal polynomial of $T$, and $\mathbb{V}=W_{1}\oplus\cdots\oplus W_{k}$ the primary decomposition of $\mathbb{V}$ for $T$.

Let $\mathbb{W}$ a subspace T-invariant of $\mathbb{V}$. I need to show that

$$\mathbb{W}=(\mathbb{W}\cap W_{1})\oplus\cdots\oplus (\mathbb{W}\cap W_{k}) $$

Here's my attempt:

Let $T_w$ be a linear operator obtained by restricting $T$ to $W$.

Then we know that the minimal polynomial of $T_w$ divides the minimal polynomial for $T$.

So the minimal polynomial of $T_w$ = $p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$ where $0 \le e_i \le r_i$

Now we know that by the primary decomposition theorem

$$\mathbb{W} = \mathbb{W_1} \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb{W_k} $$

where $\mathbb{W_i} = N(p_i(T)^{e_i})$

We see that $\mathbb{W_i} \subset W_i $ [As by the primary decomposition theorem $W_i = N(p_i(T)^{r_i})]$

Also $\mathbb{W_i} \subset \mathbb{W}$ then we see that $\mathbb{W_i} \subset \mathbb{W} \cap W_i$

> Let $w \in \mathbb{W} \cap W_i$ then $p_i(T)^{r_i}(w) = 0$ then from here can we conclude that $p_i(T)^{e_i}(w) = 0?$ This is where I am stuck. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Comment: you write $e_i | r_i$ but all we have is $e_i\leqslant r_i$.

Comment: Yeah, I did correct it . Thank you.

Comment: For last bit $w$ is killed by $p_i^{r_i}$ and by $p_1^{e_1}\dots p_k^{e_k}$ so is killed ny their $\gcd$.

Comment: Yeah, I get it..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An answer to your immediate question was already provided in the comments, but it's worth noting that the result follows from the fact that the projection operators $\pi_i:\mathbb{V}\to\mathbb{V}$ onto the generalized eigenspaces $W_i$ of $T$ are polynomials in $T$. Since $\mathbb{W}$ is invariant under $T$, $\mathbb{W}$ is also invariant under each $\pi_i$, and for every $w\in\mathbb{W}$ we have $w=\sum_i\pi_iw$ so
$$\mathbb{W}=(\mathbb{W}\cap W_1)+\cdots+(\mathbb{W}\cap W_k)$$
This sum is direct since the sum of the $W_i$'s is direct.

The fact that this holds for any $T$-invariant subspace $\mathbb{W}$ is actually equivalent to the $W_i$'s being sums of generalized eigenspaces of $T$.